# Using an Azure function to build software for Windows release?

Tags: build, continuous-integration, electron, azure-functions

I'm interested in using Azure Functions in order to build release packages for windows.  Mainly centering around electron/node.  Specifically, need to be able to do binary compiles of some modules (sqlite3 namely).  Which means VC++ Build environment + Windows SDK, Python ^2.7, Node and related...

Has anyone done this via Azure Functions?  I know there are similar questions for getting NuGet packages in an azure function, and it does seem that there is an option for the C++ tools, but not sure where to even start.

The main hope is to do this for less than the cost of a full VM for something that is likely to run less than 2-3 times a month.

Comment: Can this build be done in a regular App Service Web App?  I.e., are all the tools that you need available there?  If not, you can't do it in an Azure Function, as they use the same sandbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry - this is not a scenario suitable for Azure Functions.
The only way to include "binaries" in a Functions is by referencing assemblies you uploaded upfront. You do not have access to other binaries like VC++ build tools.

If you do not want to pay for a full fledged VM, may be think about using [VSTS](https://www.visualstudio.com) with its build and release features. With these you basically utilize MS VC++ etc. build tools in a shared and I assume cheaper way. You then are able to trigger those builds from outside with REST / service hooks.